# change properties for label in tailwind / react

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

Does anybody know how to change font properties for label in tailwind component in react js?
I need to change font size and font family for word "services"

```
<Dropdown
  arrowIcon={false}
  inline={true}
  label="Services"
> 
   <Dropdown.Item>
       <Box component={Link} to="./comservices"> <Typography>Commercial Services</Typography></Box>
  </Dropdown.Item>
  <Dropdown.Item>
      <Box component={Link} to="./residservices"><Typography>Residential Services</Typography></Box>
  </Dropdown.Item>
  <Dropdown.Item>
      <Box component={Link} to="./maintsolutions"><Typography>Maintenance Solutions</Typography></Box>
  </Dropdown.Item>
</Dropdown>
```

only default styling is available
[image]

Comment: There's not enough information, we need the name of the package from which you're importing this Dropdown component.

Comment: thats the standard dropdown for react tailwind https://flowbite-react.com/dropdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap it in a div with a className like this,

```
<div className="font-medium text-red-500">
  <Dropdown
    arrowIcon={false}
    inline={true}
    label="Services"
  > 
  ....
</div>
```

Comment: yep it did the job! thanks! Spasibo!

Comment: Ne za chto, obrashchaysya!